# Runtime crash due to private PasswordManagerUI.framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode15

After upgrading to Xcode 15.0 beta 4 the iOS app started to crash while launching, with the following error:

```
dyld[79107]: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI4ViewP8SettingsE22settingsListAppearanceQryF
  Referenced from: <071C5D97-C707-3413-B467-43E260234D2B> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21A5277g/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordManagerUI.framework/PasswordManagerUI
  Expected in:     <81D8282A-1DBD-3D15-B833-495D945BE8CA> /Users/****/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Settings.framework/Settings
```

Our project has a `Settings.framework`, so the issue seems relatable, although there is no reference on the internet for Apple's private `PasswordManagerUI.framework`. We do not link to it directly. My only assumption is that it relates to the password autofill capability that we support in our application.

Tried removing any reference to the `Settings.framework` which fixed the runtime issue, so I assume that there is something within that framework. Tried removing references to password fields in that framework, which didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Symbolicating the `PasswordManagerUI.framework` did reveal a reference to the `_$s7SwiftUI4ViewP8SettingsE22settingsListAppearanceQryF`, which also contains an actual reference to Settings, the same naming as our framework.

**Renaming our framework to something (SettingsAsd) else did resolve the runtime error.**

It seems that in Xcode15, they shipped a new internal framework called `Settings`.

So to replicate the issue couple of steps are required:

- Have a `Settings.framework` linked to the project
- Have Password autofill set-up